# how to create an odt file programmatically with java?

Tags: java, libreoffice, openoffice.org, odt, opendocument

How can I create an odt (LibreOffice/OpenOffice Writer) file with Java programmatically? A "hello world" example will be sufficient. I looked at the OpenOffice website but the documentation wasn't clear.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [ODFDOM - the OpenDocument API](https://odftoolkit.org/odfdom/)

> ODFDOM is a free OpenDocument Format
> (ODF) library. Its purpose is to
> provide an easy common way to create,
> access and manipulate ODF files,
> without requiring detailed knowledge
> of the ODF specification. It is
> designed to provide the ODF developer
> community with an easy lightwork
> programming API portable to any
> object-oriented language.
>
> The current reference implementation
> is written in Java.

```
// Create a text document from a standard template (empty documents within the JAR)
OdfTextDocument odt = OdfTextDocument.newTextDocument();

// Append text to the end of the document. 
odt.addText("This is my very first ODF test");

// Save document
odt.save("MyFilename.odt");
```

***later***

As of this writing (2016-02), we are told that these classes are deprecated... big time, and the `OdfTextDocument` API documentation tells you:

> As of release 0.8.8, replaced by org.odftoolkit.simple.TextDocument in
> Simple API.

This means you still include the same active .jar file in your project, `simple-odf-0.8.1-incubating-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, but you want to be unpacking the following .jar to get the documentation: `simple-odf-0.8.1-incubating-javadoc.jar`, rather than `odfdom-java-0.8.10-incubating-javadoc.jar`.

Incidentally, the documentation link downloads a bunch of jar files inside a .zip which says "0.6.1"... but most of the stuff inside appears to be more like 0.8.1.  I have no idea why they say "as of 0.8.8" in the documentation for the "deprecated" classes: just about everything is already marked deprecated.

The equivalent simple code to the above is then:

```
odt_doc = org.odftoolkit.simple.TextDocument.newTextDocument()
para = odt_doc.getParagraphByIndex( 0, False )
para.appendTextContent( 'stuff and nonsense' )
odt_doc.save( 'mySpankingNewFile.odt' )
```

PS am using Jython, but the Java should be obvious.

Comment: Note that JOpenDocument is GPL licensed (commercial license available) while Apache ODFDOM is (as expected) Apache licensed.

Comment: Hmm... [ODF Toolkit 0.6-incubating was released June 2013](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/downloads.html), but it's not available in Maven central repository

Comment: The ODF Toolkit project has been retired from the Apache incubator on November 27th, 2018: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/odftoolkit.html

Answer (score 9):

I have not tried it, but using [JOpenDocument](http://www.jopendocument.org/) may be an option. (It seems to be a pure Java library to generate OpenDocument files.)

Comment: The problem with JOpenDocument is that it still supports primarily spreadsheets and doesn't even have full support for text.

Comment: JOpenDocument's latest release is [1.3 from Jul 2013](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjopendocument) so it seems to be well maintained. ODFDOM seems no longer maintained, latest "release" on Jan 2012 (it's not even visible from the website) is [0.8.8-incubating](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.odftoolkit%7Codfdom-java%7C0.8.8-incubating%7Cjar).

Comment: Note that JOpenDocument is GPL licensed (commercial license available) while Apache ODFDOM is (as expected) Apache licensed.

Answer (score 3):

A complement of previously given solutions would be [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/), which allows creating office documents and reports in ODT format (from templates, composed using the LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org Writer word processor).

```
DocumentTemplateFactory templateFactory = new DocumentTemplateFactory();
DocumentTemplate template = templateFactory .getTemplate(new File("template.odt"));
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("title", "Title of my doc");
data.put("picture", new RenderedImageSource(ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/lena.png"))));
data.put("answer", "42");
//...
template.createDocument(data, new FileOutputStream("output.odt"));
```

Optionally the documents can then be converted to PDF, Word, RTF, etc. with [JODConverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/).

### Edit/update

On GitHub, [ansgarkonermann/jodreports-examples](https://github.com/ansgarkonermann/jodreports-examples) is a sample project using JODReports (with non-trivial formatting cases).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a jruby DSL for programmatically manipulating ODF documents.

https://github.com/noah/ocelot

It's not strictly java, but it aims to be much simpler to use than the ODFDOM.

Creating a hello world document is as easy as:

```
% cat examples/hello.rb
include OCELOT

Text::create "hello" do
  paragraph "Hello, world!"
end
```

There are a few more examples (including a spreadsheet example or two) [here](https://github.com/noah/ocelot/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 2):

[The ODF Toolkit](https://odftoolkit.org/) project (code hosted at [Github](https://github.com/tdf/odftoolkit)) is the new home of the former ODFDOM project, which was until 2018-11-27 a [Apache Incubator project](https://incubator.apache.org/projects/odftoolkit.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for an answer about this question for myself. I am working on a project for generating documents with different formats and I was in a bad need for library to generate ODT files.
I finally can say the that ODFToolkit with the latest version of the simple-odf library is the answer for generating text documents. 
You can find the the official page here :
[Apache ODF Toolkit(Incubating) - Simple API](https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/index.html) 
Here is  [a page to download version 0.8.1 (the latest version of Simple API)](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.odftoolkit/simple-odf/0.8.1-incubating) as I didn't find the latest version at the official page, only version 0.6.1

And here you can find [Apache ODF Toolkit (incubating) cookbook](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/document/cookbook/index.html)

Comment: The ODF Toolkit project has been retired from the Apache incubator on November 27th, 2018: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/odftoolkit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org)** to generate your reports, then [**export it to ODS**](http://www.ramkitech.com/2011/11/jsf-jpa-jasperreports-ireport.html). The nice thing about this approach is

1. you get broad support for all JasperReports output formats, e.g. PDF, XLS, HTML, etc.
2. **Jasper Studio** makes it easy to design your reports

Answer (score -1):

the solution may be JODF Java API Independentsoft company.
For example, if we want to create an Open Document file using this Java API  we could do the following:

```
import com.independentsoft.office.odf.Paragraph;
import com.independentsoft.office.odf.TextDocument;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            TextDocument doc = new TextDocument();

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
            p1.add("Hello World");

            doc.getBody().add(p1);

            doc.save("c:\\test\\output.odt", true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There are also .NET solutions for this API.