# odftoolkit NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, odt, odfdom

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791389/how-to-create-an-odt-file-programmatically-with-java) topic, and I've used odfdom library as was described, but I ve got an excption

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/dom/DocumentImpl
```

How can I deal with that? Thank you!

P.S.: Here is [gist](https://gist.github.com/iSkeeve/5232992)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Adding xercesImpl.jar (can be found in Xerces2 Java archive on http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi#binary) to my libs has solved it.