# Create an .odt file with Scala

Tags: scala, openoffice.org, libreoffice, odt, scalafx

I already had a look at: [how to create an odt file programmatically with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791389/how-to-create-an-odt-file-programmatically-with-java) but it is an old question and the solutions are using another XML-parser.

I'd like to easily create an .odt-file with Scala programmatically and write a very small WYSIWYG-editor in ScalaFX to be used within an application.

Any ideas or resources?

Comment: So what's the problem with Apache ODF Toolkit? That it doesn't use Scala's XML library?

Comment: @0__ I searched a lot but maybe I missed another, more scala-like solution :)